# Returning a value from a Javascript function that includes a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, blazor-server-side

I'm using DotNet.invokeMethodAsync to call into my server-side Blazor component which is working OK but I'm struggling with the Javascript (JS) side of things - I'm a novice JS developer.

The JS function that calls my C# method follows and works successfully:

```
function GetProperty(name) {
    console.log('GetProperty called');

    instance.invokeMethodAsync('iFrameMarshaller', name)
        .then(message => {
            console.log(message);
            return message;
        })
}
```

What I'm struggling with is how to return the results of the C# method call from my GetProperty JS function.  The GetProperty function returns before the results of the invokeMethodAsync call are returned.

I've tried to use Async/Await without success - the message variable is out of scope outside the .then statement (promise block?):

```
async function GetProperty(name) {
    console.log('GetProperty called');

    promise = instance.invokeMethodAsync('iFrameMarshaller', name)
        .then(message => {
            console.log(message);            
        })        

    var result = await promise; // wait till the promise resolves

    console.log('function outside ' + message);
}
```

I need my GetProperty function to be synchronous.  Can someone help me with this (probably very simple) problem.  Thanks.

Comment: `I need my GetProperty function to be synchronous` you can't, because it has asynchrony, you simply can't

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
async function GetProperty(name) {
  console.log("GetProperty called");

  const message = await instance
    .invokeMethodAsync("iFrameMarshaller", name);

  console.log(message);
}
```

In your code when you call `instance.invokeMethodAsync('iFrameMarshaller', name)` it return a Promise and when you call `then` on it your code will be work further. Only when your promise is fulfilled (or rejected) will the code in `then` be completed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know dotnet but with js you can try.

```
async function GetProperty(name) {
    console.log('GetProperty called');
    let message = await instance.invokeMethodAsync('iFrameMarshaller', name)
    console.log('function outside ' + message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input guys.  In the end I decided not to fight "asynchrony"and instead embrace it.  This is a simplified version of what I ended up with:

```
function GetPropertyAsync(name) {
    console.log('GetProperty called');

    instance.invokeMethodAsync('iFrameMarshaller', name)
        .then(value => successCallback(name, value), failureCallback(name))
}

function successCallback(name, value) {
    console.log("Success: " + name + " = " + value);
    ContentFrame.GetPropertyCallback(name, value);
}

function failureCallback(name) {
    console.log("Failure trying to get property with name: " + name);
}
```